# How do I fix the error of call to undefined function for add_settings_field()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I followed exactly [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-2-sections-fields-and-settings/) and I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_settings_field() in
>   /home/content/41/11334041/html/test/wp-content/themes/mothereffintheme/functions.php
>   on line 47

I'm new to working with the Wordpress API and I don't have any idea to how to fix it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72469/35498).

Comment: _to the letter_ bon français des familles  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved it in my FTP program instead of the the theme editor. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you loaded WordPress? add_settings_field() is a WordPress function rather than a default PHP function, if it's undefined it would indicate that the WordPress core hasn't been loaded. A bit of code might help.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field

Comment: How do I add the WordPress core? That is all I have in my functions.php My code is very similar to his.

Comment: Yes, I have loaded WordPress.

Comment: I'm no WordPress expert (they reside on the WordPress sub-site) but if you called your action hook (add_action('admin_init', 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options'); ) and the name of the function's second parameter matches the name of your function the add_settings_field function shouldn't be undefined. Can you confirm you did this?